# Pythonの辞書型を参照できない

Tags: python, django

Djangoを用いてWebアプリを作成しているのですが、Python-social-authを用いてTwitterでログインし、Pipelineという機能を使ってレスポンスをインターセプトしてユーザのプロファイル登録をしようとしているのですが、以下のコードでresponseの要素を参照したところ、`'tuple' object has no attribute 'description'`というエラーがでてできません。

コード

```html
def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    #Twitterの場合
    if backend.name == 'twitter':
        profile = user.get_profile()
        if profile is None:
            profile = Profile(user=user)
        print(response)
        print(response.keys())
        profile.description = response['description']
        profile.name = response.get('name')
        profile.lang = response.get('lang')
        profile.location = response.get('location')
        profile.twitterUrl = response.get('url')
        profile.save()
```

get()を使っても、[]を使っても同じエラーが出ます。

responseは正常に取得出来ていて、キーは以下のようになっています。

Key

```html
dict_keys(['profile_use_background_image', 'screen_name', 'follow_request_sent', 'is_translator', 'listed_count', 'utc_offset', 'profile_text_color', 'geo_enabled', 'has_extended_profile', 'favourites_count', 'profile_background_image_url', 'friends_count', 'profile_background_image_url_https', 'statuses_count', 'profile_background_tile', 'created_at', 'description', 'profile_image_url', 'notifications', 'status', 'profile_sidebar_border_color', 'following', 'url', 'protected', 'time_zone', 'default_profile', 'profile_background_color', 'profile_image_url_https', 'id_str', 'lang', 'followers_count', 'id', 'profile_banner_url', 'profile_link_color', 'entities', 'profile_sidebar_fill_color', 'access_token', 'contributors_enabled', 'verified', 'default_profile_image', 'location', 'is_translation_enabled', 'name'])
```

どのようにresponseの要素を参照すればいいのでしょうか

追記

Profileモデル

```html
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255, unique=True)
    icon = models.URLField(verbose_name="icon")
    registerDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    refreshDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name="The user of this profile.")
    lang = models.CharField(verbose_name="Language", max_length=255, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="description", null=True)
    twitterUrl = models.URLField(verbose_name="Twitter account URL", null=True)
    location = models.CharField(verbose_name="Location", max_length=255, null=True)
```

このサイトを参考にしております。
サイトURL:http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline

Comment: `print(response)`の結果はどうなっていますか？

Comment: response オブジェクトではなく、porfile オブジェクトのハッシュキーに `description` が存在しないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: @kotatsu様
print(response)の結果は個人情報が含まれるため記述を控えますが、私のTwitterのユーザ情報が取得できていました。

Comment: @argus様
Profileオブジェクトにはdescriptionは存在します。一応Profileのモデルを追記します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。

get_profile()を独自実装していたのですが、これが間違っていました。
そこでprofile = user.get_profile()ではなくprofile = user.profileで参照しました。